# Show a Customized Text in the Prompt List

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssas, prompt

Goal:
Display the text "All State-Province" instead of "All geographies" at the prompt list in SSRS

Problem:
I tried googling around and in the end I don't know how to solve it.

Information:
*Im using SQL server 2012

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Report Server 2012, but in 2008 the following applies.

It depends on how you're populating your parameter,

If you're declaring the values in a list

[image: SetParameterValues]

Right click on the parameter, and change the label text.

or.....

If you're populating from a query then you need to ensure that the value you're using to populate the label returns "All State-Province" instead of "All geographies".

One way round this would be to set up a calculated field on the query used to populate the dataset

something like

```
=iif(Fields!LabelText.Value="All geographies","All State-Province",Fields!LabelText.Value)
```

Then use that field as the label.

[image: ParameterQuery]

---

I see your update..

What I believe you need to do, is set up a new calculated field on your GeographyStateProvince dataset

Call it NewLabelText.

Then use the expression

```
=iif(Trim(Ucase(Fields!ParameterCaptionIndented.Value))="ALL GEOGRAPHIES","All State-Province",Fields!ParameterCaptionIndented.Value)
```

Then as shown in my previous screen print, use the new calculated field instead of `ParameterCaptionIndented`

---

You can see your datasets on the left of this picture.

[image: Datasets]

Comment: In this situation, it is "If you're populating from a query then you need to ensure that the value you're using to populate the label returns "All State-Province" instead of "All geographies"."

Comment: Yes, that is what it will do... If it's returning "All geographies" in the query then the expression will swap the value and return back "All State-Province" instead, so if you use that calculated field as your label value, you will see "All State-Province"

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Exactly where do I apply the source code "=iif(Fields!LabelText.Value="All geographies","All State-Province",Fields!LabelText.Value)"? Of course, in SSRS but exacly where should I do it? I have applied more picture to understand deeply. Please inform me if you need more information!

Comment: @FullMetalGame I updated my answer, you basically need to add it as a new calculated field in the dataset that is populating the values for the parameter.

Comment: How do I add a new calculated filed in the dataset in the query designer? Sorry, I cannot find that functionality. If possible you can display it by using picture(s).

Comment: Your datasets are on the far left hand side, you have 4. GeographyCountry, DataSet1, GeographyCity and GeographyStateProvince. Right click on GeographyStateProvince and one of the options should be to add a calculated field.